Getting JSON extraction in Jmeter based on conditions
I have a response with nested array and I need to extract id's for objects which have attribute "isFolder" = false. How can I do that?
I've tried using JSON extractor with pattern
$.data.tileGrid.items[?(@.isFolder == false)][1].id

also tried get an array and then just pickup a random value with a 0-match
$..[?(@.isFolder == false)].id

but didnt work - debug sampler shows an empty variable. response looks like
{
    "data": {
        "navigation": {
            "hasNextPage": true,
            "urlNextPage": "\/docs\/shared\/?nav-folder_list_14=page-2",
            "pageSize": 50,
            "currentPage": 1
        },
        "tileGrid": {
            "itemType": "BX.Disk.TileGrid.Item",
            "id": "folder_list_14",
            "items": [
                {
                    "isFile": false,
                    "canAdd": true,
                    "link": "\/docs\/shared\/path\/%D0%9F%D0%9A%D0%9E\/",
                    "isFolder": true,
                    "id": "6789192",
                    "isSymlink": false
                },
                ...
                {
                    "isFile": true,
                    "canAdd": true,
                    "link": "\/docs\/shared\/path\/%D0%9F%D0%9A%D0%9E\/",
                    "isFolder": false,
                    "id": "6789192",
                    "isSymlink": false
                }
             ]
         }
     }
}


To extract ids where "isFolder": false, use:
Python with jsonpath-ng:
from jsonpath_ng.ext import parse

# JSON response
json_response = {
    "data": {
        "tileGrid": {
            "items": [
                {"isFolder": True, "id": "123456"},
                {"isFolder": False, "id": "6789192"}
            ]
        }
    }
}

jsonpath_expr = parse("$.data.tileGrid.items[?(@.isFolder == false)].id")
ids = [match.value for match in jsonpath_expr.find(json_response)]
print(ids)  # Output: ['6789192']

JMeter JSON Extractor:
JSONPath: $.data.tileGrid.items[?(@.isFolder == false)].id
Match No.: -1 (for all matches)
Variable: nonFolderIds
This will extract 6789192. Debug to confirm variable values.
Make sure to test pass valid JSON. use any available tools to validate JSON data.

The $..[?(@.isFolder == false)].id  expression is correct

Make sure that the response you're getting is valid JSON
More information: JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios
